# Export pagetree with images?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

Is it possible to export a pagetree to .t3d with images? Images are embedded as "Text & Images" elements. I could export pages, but images didn't follow.

Answer (score 1):

Images has to be moved separately to the same path (either in fileadmin or in uploads) in order to do a proper export/import. If you check the file, all file paths are there in the export.

Source: 
https://wiki.typo3.org/Faq/copy_parts_of_a_running_TYPO3_system_to_another_server

Comment: It seems not to be the case (any longer). The .t3d contains no paths, only numbers and codes.

Comment: Oh, those are references to sys_file or sys_file_reference table, so you need to export those tables to get the filenames there.

Comment: There are some file references. But still I must re-add all images into hundreds of content elements. Here's my config: http://prnt.sc/c9tdwf

Comment: I googled a little bit and there is this bug report related to what you are describing. https://forge.typo3.org/issues/67188 A solution there is suggested. If the file references are exported and imported properly and files are in the same folders on the import system, the import script should remap those IDs into the new ones and files should be present. Are you importing to the 6.1 installation as well?